# Vertex cover of minimal graph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, computability, vertex-cover

I'm looking for algorithm that, for given undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, find graph $G'=(V,E')$ with minimal amount of edges that have same vertex cover as G. I mean, vertices $U$ are vertex cover of $G$ iff they are vertex cover of $G'$.
I understood that a polynomial algorithm exists, it's mean without finding the vertex cover of $G$, but I found only a non-polynomial one.

Comment: I thought about edge cover, maybe this is the solution?

Comment: No, I checked it and it looks like not related to edge cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm to compute $G'$ is really easy: just return $G$.

Indeed, given any $G=(V,E)$ the only graph $G'=(V, E')$ such that $U \subseteq V$ is a vertex cover of $G$ iff $U$ is a vertex cover of $G'$ is $G$ itself.

To prove this you can show that we must simultaneously have $E \subseteq E'$  and $E' \subseteq E$.

**Proof that $E \subseteq E'$**: Suppose towards a contradiction that $E \nsubseteq E'$. Then $\exists (u,v) \in E \setminus E'$. The set
$U = V \setminus \{u,v\}$ is a vertex cover for $G'$ but not for $G$.

**Proof that $E' \subseteq E$**: Suppose towards a contradiction that $E' \nsubseteq E$. Then $\exists (u,v) \in E' \setminus E$. The set
$U = V \setminus \{u,v\}$ is a vertex cover for $G$ but not for $G'$.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're right, a basic example, cube with one additional vertex. G={V,E}, V={1,2,3,4,5}, E={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}.{4,5}, {5,2}}, have only one vertex cover U={2,4} same as E'={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}.

Comment: The are many vertex covers of your example graph. A trivial one different from $\{2,4\}$ is $V$ itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check how the original question was defined but only tomorrow. Are solution right but too trivial.

Comment: Thank you @Steven, but I think you wrong. $G=\{V,E\}, V=\{1,2,3,4\}, E=\{ \{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$ have same vertex cover as $E'=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\}\}$ or I missed something

Comment: They do not have the same vertex covers. $\{2,4\}$ is a vertex cover for $G'=(V, E')$ but not for $G$, since it does not cover edge $(1,3)$.

Comment: Sorry, you right my example wrong. I need to think a bit more.

Comment: I think you right, but you shouldn't proof that $E'\subseteq E$ because it's part of the question deffinition.

Comment: @ChaosPredictor. It's never stated in your question that $G'$ must be a subgraph of $G$, so I didn't assume it.

Comment: I still think should remove the proof of $E'\subseteq E$, because: "...$G'$ with minimal amount of edges that have same vertex as $G$..."